# phonegap again trying to display a large table using overflow to add scrollbars

Tags: cordova, overflow

I have a large table and it's fine on a normal site, just having trouble putting it on an app.
A colleague suggested using an overflow auto around the table using jQuery but it doesn't work.
Has anyone got any better ideas or know how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you take a look at iscroll (http://cubiq.org/iscroll)

It implemenents native scrolling behaviour with javascript and webkit-transitions